# mutliple images in a div with different sizes

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images, 1 (left) is suppose to be big, the other 3 next to it, and all of them in a container.  The 3 on the right need to be all the same size.  I can't get my images to show next to each other no matter what i do with the sizing.  Am I missing something really easy?

Comment: could you post a link and show your code? A reduced example of the markup and css on jsfiddle is fine too

Comment: You could also read this before going any further : http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure each image has a `float:left`

by adding that, each img will float next to each other...

Comment: As replaced inline elements, images _are_ displayed next to each other by default.

Comment: thank you very much, adding the float:left did it, lol so i was missing something really easy :) appreciate the help :)

Comment: np! - feel free to accept the Answer and vote it up if you can :)

Comment: I think that accepted it :) can't vote up tho sorry :(